# unable to get datepicker to work with ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm displaying a table row for each item in my `$scope.items` through an `ng-repeat`
Calling the `ng-repeat` prevents the jquery-UI datepicker popup from appearing. Though if I remove the `ng-repeat`, it works but I will only get one row.

Why is this? How can I make it so that for each item in my items array, there's a row in the table with working date pickers. I guess the `datepicker()` function gets called before the ng-repeat?

I have html that looks like this

```
<div class="content" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
    <div mydirective>

    </div>
</div>
```

**The controller**

```
 app.controller("tableCtrl", function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.items = [
            "test1", "test2","test3"
        ];
    });
```

**And finally my directive 'mydirective' looks like this**

```
app.directive("mydirective", function ()
    {
        return {
            templateUrl: "tables.html"
        }
    });
```

**tables.html**

```
 <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>test</option>
                <option>test</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
      <script>
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a custom datepicker directive that runs for each of your repeated elements. Eg (untested):

```
angular.module('my.directives.datepicker', [])
.directive('myDatePicker', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',      
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            // timeout internals are called once directive rendering is complete
            $timeout(function(){                    
                $(elem).datePicker();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: +1 There's also ui-date from the AngularUI team.  :)  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date